# Saving images more efficiently in favor of minimum memory use

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uiimage

I'm observing the Pasteboard for changes, that include images. The amount of memory I can use is limited, so most images make the program result in a jetsam crash due to their size. Is it possible to store them more efficiently?

Currently I'm using this code to store them:

```objectivec
for (UIImage* image in [_pasteboard images]) {
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by making a different process with more memory do the work. The original process only sends a notification now.

Answer (score 1):

All of those images are staying in memory in this loop, which is causing your memory use problem. You can help by adding an autorelease pool inside the loop:

```swift
for (UIImage* image in [_pasteboard images]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

That will cause each image's memory to be reclaimed at the end of the current pass through the loop.

I'm removing the "core-data" tag since this question is not about Core Data.

Comment: That's a good answer, but I have already tried it. Jetsam kills it as soon as the NSData is created by UIImagePNGRepresentation. I've got less than 6MB of RAM available to use.

Comment: When you ask a question, you should really say what you have tried already.